# GroupBy Date from Datetime variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linqpad

I have a database in this format:

```
Datetime             | Air Temperature
---------------------+-----------------
...                  |
01.12.2013 00:00:00  | 2
01.12.2013 01:00:00  | 2
01.12.2013 02:00:00  | 2
01.12.2013 03:00:00  | 1.7
01.12.2013 04:00:00  | 2
01.12.2013 05:00:00  | 2
01.12.2013 06:00:00  | 2.2
...
```

and trying to use linq from VB.Net to group the results for each day across a date range:

```
Dim query = (From i In db _
    Where i.Datetime > #12/1/2013 00:00# AndAlso i.Datetime < #1/1/2014 00:00# _
    Select i).GroupBy(Function(f) f.Datetime.Day)

Console.WriteLine(query)
```

but query output is grouped by each item in database (each hour) instead day:

```
[
  {
    "Key": 1,
    "Values": [
      {
        "Datetime": "2013-12-01T00:00:00",
        "AirTemperature": 2.0,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": 1,
    "Values": [
      {
        "Datetime": "2013-12-01T01:00:00",
        "AirTemperature": 2.0,
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

First I used `i.DateTime.Date` as grouping operator, but as that didn't work the way I wanted, I thought that converting Datetime object to short date string can get me there. It didn't change a thing, and being fresh linq user, I thought to ask for help.

Comment: Do you want a single aggregate temperature (e.g. average) per day, if so after the GroupBy you can use something like Select(Function(key,values) values.Average(Function(v) v.t))

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted - extract max and min temperature per day, so I needed grouping... but still can't get there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GroupBy extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of TKey,TSource), each [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) represents a collection of items and exposes a `Key` property which in this case will be the date. You can apply a Select to project the groupings and apply Min and Max aggregates to the items, e.g. (Note: as I don't have the database I've set up some example data for the query result):

```
Structure Item
    Public DateTime As DateTime
    Public Temp As Double
End Structure

Sub Main()
    ' Test data
    Dim query = {
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 00:00#, .Temp = 2},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 01:00#, .Temp = 2},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 02:00#, .Temp = 2},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 03:00#, .Temp = 1.7},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 04:00#, .Temp = 2},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 05:00#, .Temp = 2},
        New Item With {.DateTime = #12/1/2013 06:00#, .Temp = 2.2}
    }

    ' Aggregate with extension methods
    Dim aggregated =
        query.GroupBy(Function(item) item.DateTime.Date) _
             .Select(Function(grouping) _
                     New With {
                        .DateTime = grouping.Key,
                        .Max = grouping.Max(Function(item) item.Temp),
                        .Min = grouping.Min(Function(item) item.Temp)
                        })

    ' Aggregate with sugared LINQ
    Dim aggregated2 =
        From item In query
        Group item By key = item.DateTime.Date Into Group
        Select New With {
            .DateTime = key,
            .Min = Group.Min(Function(item) item.Temp),
            .Max = Group.Max(Function(item) item.Temp)}

    ' Show aggregated results
    For Each item In aggregated2
        Console.WriteLine(item.DateTime & " " & item.Min & " " & item.Max)
    Next
End Sub
```

For reference check out the [LINQ Query Samples - Grouping Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737908)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and your answer. Your example does what it says, and it helped me see that also my query above works as expected on your example data. But not with a database I work on, so I'll assume that I have some piping problem between the code and Access database from LinqPad.

Comment: Indeed, as assumed the problem seems to be with [MSAccessDataContextDriver.lpx](http://blog.denouter.net/2013/11/ms-access-in-linqpad.html) LinqPad driver. After migrating Access database to SQL server grouping works as expected.